# Exception in Android Google Map Api V2

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I tried this piece of code from an example,but get exceptions in onResume().I can't understand what's the problem?Anyone can give suggestion for this?

**My code**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
        implements LocationSource, LocationListener{

final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
private GoogleMap myMap;
TextView tvLocInfo;

LocationManager myLocationManager = null;
OnLocationChangedListener myLocationListener = null;
Criteria myCriteria;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvLocInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locinfo);

    FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    MapFragment myMapFragment 
        = (MapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    myMap = myMapFragment.getMap();

    myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    myCriteria = new Criteria();
    myCriteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    myLocationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_legalnotices:
        String LicenseInfo = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(
                getApplicationContext());
        AlertDialog.Builder LicenseDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        LicenseDialog.setTitle("Legal Notices");
        LicenseDialog.setMessage(LicenseInfo);
        LicenseDialog.show();
        return true;    
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);   
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

    if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //Register for location updates using a Criteria, and a callback on the specified looper thread.
        myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                0L,             //minTime
                0.0f,           //minDistance
                myCriteria,     //criteria
                this,           //listener
                null);          //looper

        //Replaces the location source of the my-location layer.
        myMap.setLocationSource(this);

    }else{
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, RQS_GooglePlayServices);    
    }

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    myMap.setLocationSource(null);
    myLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void activate(OnLocationChangedListener listener) {
    myLocationListener = listener;
}

@Override
public void deactivate() {
    myLocationListener = null;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (myLocationListener != null) {
        myLocationListener.onLocationChanged(location);

        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lon = location.getLongitude();

        tvLocInfo.setText(
                "lat: " + lat + "\n" +
                "lon: " + lon);
    }
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

**Logcat view**

```
02-12 10:56:34.907: W/dalvikvm(1986): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e55258)
02-12 10:56:34.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1986): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 10:56:34.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1986): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.androidmapsv2/com.example.androidmapsv2.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no provider_s found for criteria
02-12 10:56:34.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1986):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2491)
02-12 10:56:34.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1986):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
02-12 10:56:34.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1986):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-12 10:56:34.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1986):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
02-12 10:56:34.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1986):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1179)
02-12 10:56:34.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1986):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-12 10:56:34.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1986):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-12 10:56:34.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1986):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4508)
02-12 10:56:34.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1986):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 10:56:34.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1986):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-12 10:56:34.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1986):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
02-12 10:56:34.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1986):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
02-12 10:56:34.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1986):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-12 10:56:34.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1986): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no provider_s found for criteria
02-12 10:56:34.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1986):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1331)
02-12 10:56:34.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1986):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
02-12 10:56:34.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1986):     at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(ILocationManager.java:671)
02-12 10:56:34.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1986):     at android.location.LocationManager._requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:582)
02-12 10:56:34.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1986):     at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:563)
02-12 10:56:34.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1986):     at com.example.androidmapsv2.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:88)
02-12 10:56:34.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1986):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1159)
02-12 10:56:34.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1986):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4553)
02-12 10:56:34.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1986):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
02-12 10:56:34.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1986):     ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the Android-Developers page where you can find the declaration of the [`requestLocationUpdates` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.location.LocationListener,%20android.os.Looper%29).

```
public void requestLocationUpdates (long minTime, float minDistance, Criteria criteria, LocationListener listener, Looper looper)
```

There you can see what Exceptions the method throws

```
Throws
    IllegalArgumentException    if criteria is null
    IllegalArgumentException    if listener is null
    SecurityException   if no suitable permission is present
```

If you now look at your code

```
    myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            0L,             //minTime
            0.0f,           //minDistance
            myCriteria,     //criteria
            this,           //listener
            null);          //looper
```

and your Exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {...}: 
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no provider_s found for criteria
                   ^^^^^^^ this                              and this  ^^^^
```

aswell as

```
at com.example.androidmapsv2.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:88)
```

you can see that the `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown in line 88. The reason for this is that `criteria` is `null` when `requestLocationUpdates` is called.

The initialization of your `criteria` in `OnCreate` is not enough. 
When your `OnResume` is called you need to do a null check to confirm that the `criteria` is instantiated.

Comment: yes,i figured it out couple of days ago.Lack of a provider causes it.You also correctly figured it,thanks.